# Finding id of div that is a parent somewhere up the chain?

Tags: jquery, html

If you have a click function for a link in a div, and want to know the id of a div that the click div is a child of (maybe 3rd child, maybe 5th child), is this the way to get it (it's working, but I'm wondering if there's a better way if you know the class of the parent?)

```
<div class="cont" id="c_22">
    <div>
        <div>         
            <div class="del"><a href="#">DELETE</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This within click function...

```
alert($(this).closest('.cont').attr('id'))
```

Sometimes the "del" div has more divs surrounding it, so I can't rely on going up a certain number of divs. The inner divs have other stuff in them, but I've left it out to keep things easy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nope, there is no better way.

Comment: If you know the class of the div you're looking for, then what you have is what I would use.

Comment: That are pretty much the 3 fastest solutions : http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-index-selector-property. Careful with the last one, if closest found no element, there will be an error.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll stick with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already used one of the best way of doing it. You can also use `.parents()`:

```
 $(this).parents('.cont').attr('id')
```

Comment: If he had the *best* solution, why suggest him an other solution which is worst? \*-\*

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: to show that there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that It will help you

```
$(".cont a").on('click', function(){
  console.log($("a").parent().closest('.cont').attr('id'))
});
```